# Integration test for DB H2 and for controller

Tags: java, testing, integration-testing, h2

I have two integration test in my program and unfortunately both doesn't work. I don't know this is good idea to write both problem in one case but i try.
Firstly i show my db integration test :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class TeamDatabaseIntegrationTest {

    @MockBean
    private TeamRepository teamRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager testEntityManager;

    @Test
    public void testDb() {
        Team team = new Team(1L, "teamName", "teamDescription", "krakow", 7);
        Team team2 = new Team(2L, "teamName", "teamDescription", "krakow", 7);
        testEntityManager.persist(team);
        testEntityManager.flush();

        Iterable<Team> teams = teamRepository.findAll();
        assertThat(teams).hasSize(2).contains(team, team2);
    }
```

In this test i add 2 elements to my db and expect that this test is ok but it return this :

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected size:<2> but was:<0> in:
<[]>
```

In my second test i want to test controller method show all elements.
This is my method in cotroller:

```
@GetMapping("/teams")
    public List<TeamDto> findAll() {
        return teamService.findAll();
    }
```

My test method for this look like this :
@SpringJUnitWebConfig(classes = CrewApplication.class)

```
public class TeamControllerMethodIntegrationTest {
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception
    {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.webApplicationContext).build();
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    void getAccount() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/teams")
                .accept(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/json;charset=UTF-8")))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$version").value(null))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$name").value("Apacze"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$createOn").value(null))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("modifiedOn").value(null))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$description").value("grupa programistow"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$city").value("Włocławek"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$headcount").value(null));
    }
}
```

In this case i have other error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.softwaremind.crew.people.integrationTest.TeamControllerMethodIntegrationTest.getAccount
```

I fight with this tests over week and i really have no idea how to repair this.

Answer (score 0):

In your first case replace

```
@MockBean
private TeamRepository teamRepository;
```

with

```
@Autowired
private TeamRepository teamRepository;
```

(you cannot use mock and expect it to return values from in memory db)

For you second test.  Remove @SpringJUnitWebConfig and annotate it with

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest()
```

and add Autowired to MockMvc

```
@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;
```

EDIT

Additionally remove your `setup()` method as everything should be already configured. (and then you also don't need webApplicationContext attribute) and assert that the Test annotation you are using is org.junit.Test (check your imports)

Comment: Thanks i add solution above Your answere

Comment: When I add @Autowired on mockmvc i have an error that mockmvc is null

Comment: @MagdalenaRumakowicz In your controller test add `TeamController.class` in `WebMvcTest()`